# How can I delete third-party Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I got Google Maps implement in my website but I want to block the cookie ("NID") until the user allows the cookies on this website. Is there a way to block the cookie with JavaScript?

I'm using

```
document.cookie = "BpSessionID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";
```

To delete other cookies but this isn't working for third party cookies.

Answer (score 0):

[DUB] see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870812/2064909

Go here for details: https://cookie-script.com/how-to-block-third-party-cookies.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.